# C++ STL--make_heap with pair<int,string> as data type

Tags: c++, heap

I know how does heap work and how it arranges min and max elements. It is easy, if vector contains only `int`, to apply make_heap in STL. But how to apply `make_heap()` if vector contains structure of string and int. Iwant to make heap based on `int` value in structure.
Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried? In particular, did you try giving an explicit comparison function?

Comment: I don't know how to do with comparison fun...

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked, but doesn't `pair` come with an ordering that does what you want?

Comment: @Hurkyl The default ordering for `std::pair` is the lexicographic ordering. That implies that both elements of the pair are taken into account for the ordering, not only the first. For the heap the OP is about to build it may (perhaps) not matter, but for stable sort it would.

Comment: You don't need your own comparison function. See my answer and links therein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide comparison function for your structure:

```
struct A
{
 int x, y;
};

struct Comp
{
   bool operator()(const A& s1, const A& s2)
   {
       return s1.x < s2.x && s1.y == s2.y;
   }
};

std::vector<A> vec;
std::make_heap(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Comp());
```

Comment: Why the second condition (`s1.y == s2.y`) in the comparator?

Comment: it's only example didnt care about comparison logic

Comment: I don't think there is any need for the comparison function, unless you want to specify your own logic. If you want lexicographical comparison, just use the default.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [`std::make_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) with `std::pair<int, std::string>` directly because [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) has the required less-than comparison [`operator<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp). There is even an example in the reference linked above using that particular instantiation of `std::pair`.