# Heap comparision between object and static position

Tags: c++, heap, a-star, comparison-operators

I'm working on pathfinding for a 2D tile game.  I've found [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190269/c-stl-make-heap-with-pairint-string-as-data-type), but I'm not sure how to do create the comparison operator when `heap compares i <> i+i`, when `i need manhattan(i) <> manhattan(i+1)?`  I'm insanely rusty with cpp so go easy on me.

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int> coord;

int manhattan(coord start, coord goal){
    return (std::abs(start.get<0> - goal.get<0>) + \ 
            std::abs(start.get<1> - goal.get<1>) )
}

bool operator()((const coord& left, const coord& right){
   return manhattan(left, ???) < manhattan(right, ???);    
}

vector pathfinding(coord start, coord goal){
  //using A* format
  vector<coord> open;

  while(open){
      //how can I compare indexes to goal parameter?
      std::sort_heap(open.begin(), open.end()); 

      current = open.front();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a [lambda function](http://blog.smartbear.com/c-plus-plus/c11-tutorial-lambda-expressions-the-nuts-and-bolts-of-functional-programming/) to create a local comparator for each call of `pathfinding`. Also, don't forget to pass it to [`std::sort_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort_heap/). Try this:

```
vector pathfinding(coord start, coord goal) {
  // using A* format
  vector<coord> open;
  auto comp = [&goal](const coord& lhs, const coord& rhs) {
    return manhattan(lhs, goal) > manhattan(rhs, goal); // greater-than, for a min-heap
  };

  while(open){
    std::sort_heap(open.begin(), open.end(), comp);

    ...
  }
}
```

`comp` is initialized to a lambda object (like a lambda in Python or an anonymous function in JavaScript). The `[&goal]` part means to "capture" the `goal` variable by reference for use in the lambda. It's like a custom class with a member variable that stores a reference to `goal`, and has an `operator()` that compares two `coord`s using `goal`.

Also, I don't think that you should be using `std::sort_heap`... Use [`std::push_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/) and [`std::pop_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/) (see the [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/#example) in the linked documentation). The idea is to call `std::make_heap` once at the beginning, and use `push/pop_heap` to maintain the heap when adding/removing. No need to sort it every iteration. Example:

```
// to push "direction" onto the heap:
open.push_back(direction);
std::push_heap(open.begin(), open.end(), comp);

// to pop "current" off of the heap:
std::pop_heap(open.begin(), open.end(), comp);
current = open.pop_back();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a super helpful follow up of an explanation.  And I was looking at that documentation, but I see no reason  why I can't just used sort_heap and avoid the push/pops?

Comment: How are you currently pushing/popping values onto/off of the heap?

Comment: I was just using open.push_back( direction ) at the bottom and then sort_heap(), open.front(), open.erase(0) at the top of the loop?

Comment: I've edited with example usage. You don't need to sort every iteration; just use those two functions, and the heap will be maintained (largest value at `open.front()`)

Comment: Actually, you probably want a min-heap for A* instead of a max-heap... I've edited `comp` in my answer to reflect that